# Getting smooth animations in Line Chart D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was working on a real time line chart in d3 and finally got my chart to update the x axis and shift it left and it works fine. I was also able to shift the chart lines (paths) however for some reason the animation is not smooth.`

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const MARGIN = {TOP: 50, BOTTOM: 50, LEFT: 50, RIGHT: 50};
const WIDTH = svg.attr('width') - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT;
const HEIGHT = svg.attr('height') - MARGIN.TOP - MARGIN.BOTTOM;

const limit = 60;
const duration = 500;
let dataList = [];

let g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate( ${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${MARGIN.TOP} )`);

g.append('defs').append('clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'clip2')
    .append('rect')
     .attr('x', 0)
     .attr('y', 0)
     .attr('width', WIDTH)
     .attr('height', HEIGHT);

// ParseTime

const timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
     .range([0, WIDTH]);

const valueScale = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([0, 10])
     .range([HEIGHT, 0]);

const line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x((d) => timeScale(d.time))
    .y((d) => valueScale(d.value));

const xAxis =  d3.axisBottom(timeScale);

const axisCall = g.append('g')
                  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${HEIGHT})`);

axisCall.call(xAxis);

g.append('g')
 .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
 .call(d3.axisLeft(valueScale))

let pathsG = g.append('g').attr('id', 'paths').attr('class', 'paths').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip2)');

function updateChart() {
 let now = Date.now();
  dataList.push({
   time: now,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  });
  
  // Shift domain
  timeScale.domain([now - ((limit - 2) * duration), now - duration]);
  
  axisCall.transition().duration(duration).ease(d3.easeLinear, 2).call(xAxis);
  
  let minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data(dataList);
  let minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
         .append('g')
         .attr('class', 'minerLine')
         .merge(minerG);
  
  let minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
   return [d];
  });
  
  let minerSVGenter = minerSVG.enter()
                 .append('path').attr('class', 'line')
           .style('stroke', '#D073BA')
           .style('fill', 'none')
              .merge(minerSVG)
           .transition()
           .duration(duration)
           .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
           .attr('d', line(dataList))
           .attr('transform', null);
  
  }

setInterval(function(){ 
   //console.log('hello');
  updateChart();
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
    <title>Real-time Line Chart D3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <svg width="960" height="500">
    </svg>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`
I used the code from the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/Sohalt/9715be30ba57e00f2275d49247fa7118/43a24a4dfa44738a58788d05230407294ab7a348

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the graph, one path seems to be thicker. If we look at the DOM we see many paths, every update brings a new path into the DOM.

This is because of how you have create the update function:

Every update you add a random value:

```
dataList.push({
    time: now,
  value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
});
```

Then you use that data to enter `g` elements.

```
let minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data(dataList);
let minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
    .append('g')
    ...
```

But, the data here is the array of points. We only want one `g` per series, not data point. So what happens is many `g` elements are created right away, and one is added every update.

Then with every new `g`, you append a path and draw it with the points in `dataList`.

```
let minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
  return [d];
});

let minerSVGenter = minerSVG.enter()
    .append('path')
    ...
    .attr('d', line(dataList))
    ...
```

The simplest fix only adds two characters:

```
let minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data([dataList]);
```

By using `[dataList]` instead of `dataList` we are only ever entering or updating one element, not one for every coordinate in `dataList`.

While I might propose a few other changes, here's your code with that one change:

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const MARGIN = {TOP: 50, BOTTOM: 50, LEFT: 50, RIGHT: 50};
const WIDTH = svg.attr('width') - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT;
const HEIGHT = svg.attr('height') - MARGIN.TOP - MARGIN.BOTTOM;

const limit = 60;
const duration = 500;
let dataList = [];

let g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate( ${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${MARGIN.TOP} )`);

g.append('defs').append('clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'clip2')
    .append('rect')
     .attr('x', 0)
     .attr('y', 0)
     .attr('width', WIDTH)
     .attr('height', HEIGHT);

// ParseTime

const timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
     .range([0, WIDTH]);

const valueScale = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([0, 10])
     .range([HEIGHT, 0]);

const line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x((d) => timeScale(d.time))
    .y((d) => valueScale(d.value));

const xAxis =  d3.axisBottom(timeScale);

const axisCall = g.append('g')
                  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${HEIGHT})`);

axisCall.call(xAxis);

g.append('g')
 .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
 .call(d3.axisLeft(valueScale))

let pathsG = g.append('g').attr('id', 'paths').attr('class', 'paths').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip2)');

function updateChart() {
 let now = Date.now();
  dataList.push({
   time: now,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  });
  
  // Shift domain
  timeScale.domain([now - ((limit - 2) * duration), now - duration]);
  
  axisCall.transition().duration(duration).ease(d3.easeLinear, 2).call(xAxis);
  
  let minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data([dataList]);
  let minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
         .append('g')
         .attr('class', 'minerLine')
         .merge(minerG);
  
  let minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
   return [d];
  });
  
  let minerSVGenter = minerSVG.enter()
                 .append('path').attr('class', 'line')
           .style('stroke', '#D073BA')
           .style('fill', 'none')
              .merge(minerSVG)
           .transition()
           .duration(duration)
           .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
           .attr('d', line(dataList))
           .attr('transform', null);
  
  }

setInterval(function(){ 
   //console.log('hello');
  updateChart();
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
    <title>Real-time Line Chart D3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <svg width="960" height="500">
    </svg>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```